# i am getting time difference when multiple tabs are opened in browser (Angular 2)(spring boot)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

[image]I'am fetching server time from back-end(in java) after login is successful and 
in interval have added 1 sec

```
      Observable.interval(1000).map(() => {
        return this.time.add(1, 'seconds');
      }).subscribe(currentServerTime => {
        this.currentServerTime = currentServerTime ;
        this.timerService.next(this.currentServerTime );
      }, error => {
        this._errorService.handleError(error);
      });
```

and after every 1 min again call is made to server to fetch current server time.

it displays correct server time ;but  when i open multiple tabs of same webpage then time difference is observed.
is their any way to sync all  tabs opened..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue I made the switch to `this.interval = setInterval(() => { //do stuff }, 1000);`
Use `clearInterval(this.interval)` to delete it.

Observables are async when the tab is inactive you will notice that it can take up double the time.